# How do I set the default permission of 775 for all new files and directories in server?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, chmod

I'm trying to set the permission of any new files to 775 by default (inherited from parent folder), so that every user group can edit these files. I have found and followed this tutorial with no success:

http://knackforge.com/blog/vannia/setup-default-group-permissions-new-files-created-under-specific-directory-debianubuntu

It doesn't work. I have to use `sudo chmod -Rv 775 .` every time to set all the files. How do I make this happen automatically?

Comment: Regardless of the solution, keep in mind that `755` includes the executable bit for all users; `o+rw` might be more suitable (`o` for others, `g` for group or `g+rw,o+rw` for both).

Comment: ok, but how i can set it to default?

Comment: Not an expert, but acls and/or umasks might get you what you need.

Comment: I don't suppose the directories you are concerned about are SAMBA dir's are they? you can specify a create mask in your smb.conf to address it. have you considered using the SetGID bit (eg: 2775)? SetGid when applied to a folder, causes objects created in the folder to assume the group value from the folder, including subfolders. I usually have my trees owned by Admin:users, and apply 2750 to the folder. that way all the objects created in the tree become owned by Admin:users automatically, so that my users can read/exec, and my Admin can edit/delete.